# How does the price of Temmie Armour change?

Tags: undertale

I know that the Temmie armour gets discounted every time you die, but what is the discount function? When I unlocked it, the price was 6500 Gold, how many more times do I need to die before it drops below 1000?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Temy Armor](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Temy_Armor) drops at a linear rate of 1000 gold/death for the first 5 deaths, then drops to 500 gold/death, then 200 after 10 deaths. To get the price to 1000 gold the player must die 19 times. The minimum the armor can get to is 750 gold, with 23 deaths.

[Source](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Temy_Armor)

Comment: Maybe it wasn't 6500 then!